# Share global logger among module/classes

Tags: ruby, global-variables, logging

What is the best (proper) way to share a logger instance amongst many ruby classes?

Right now I just created the logger as a global $logger = Logger.new variable, but I have a feeling that there is a better way to do this without using a global var.

If I have the following:

```
module Foo
  class A
  class B
  class C
  ...
  class Z
end
```

what is the best way to share a logger instances among all the classes?  Do I declare/create the logger in the Foo module somehow or is just using the global $logger fine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby - share logger instance among module/classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917566/ruby-share-logger-instance-among-module-classes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a constant in the module:

```
module Foo
  Logger = Logger.new
  class A
  class B
  class C
  ...
  class Z
end
```

Then you can do `Logger.log('blah')` in your classes.  Since we're shadowing the global constant `Logger` with `Foo::Logger`, this means that if you want to refer to the `Logger` class within the `Foo` module, you have to use the scope resolution: `::Logger`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a singleton Logger for your app, so every reference will be to the same object.

```
require 'singleton'

class Logger
  include Singleton
end

l = Logger.instance
k = Logger.instance

puts k.object_id == l.object_id #returns true
```

Comment: Please read ["The Chainsaw Infanticide Logger Manuever"](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_frm/thread/aaec68ab9088e3ef/d0f054886e0bf71c?lnk=gst&q=chainsaw#d0f054886e0bf71c) [sic] before turning Logger into a singleton for everyone. Subclass it first, or (as Pesto suggests in another answer) create a constant pointing to an instance you like.