# Share state between test classes and tested classes

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm experimenting with RSpec.
Since I don't like mocks, I would like to emulate a console print using a `StringIO` object.

So, I want to test that the `Logger` class writes `Welcome` to the console. To do so, my idea was to override the `puts` method used inside `Logger` from within the spec file, so that nothing actually changes when using `Logger` elsewhere.

Here's some code:

```
describe Logger do
    Logger.class_eval do
        def puts(*args)
            ???.puts(*args)
        end
    end

    it 'says "Welcome"' do
end
```

Doing this way, I need to share some `StringIO` object (which would go where the question marks are now) between the `Logger` class and the test class.

I found out that when I'm inside RSpec tests, `self` is an instance of `Class`. What I thought initially was to do something like this:

```
Class.class_eval do
    attr_accessor :my_io
    @my_io = StringIO.new
end
```

and then replace `???` with `Class.my_io`.

When I do this, a thousand bells ring in my head telling me it's not a clean way to do this.

What can I do?

PS: I still don't get this:

```
a = StringIO.new
a.print('a')
a.string # => "a"
a.read # => "" ??? WHY???
a.readlines # => [] ???
```

Still: `StringIO.new('hello').readlines # => ["hello"]`

Answer (score 1):

To respond to your last concern, `StringIO` simulates file behavior. When you write/print to it, the input cursor is positioned after the last thing you wrote. If you write something and want to read it back, you need to reposition yourself (e.g. with `rewind`, `seek`, etc.), per http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html

In contrast, `StringIO.new('hello')` establishes `hello` as the initial contents of the string while leaving in the position at 0. In any event, the `string` method just returns the contents, independent of position.

Comment: And that fits quite well indeed :). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you have an issue with the test double mechanism in RSpec.

That said, your approach for sharing a method works, although:

- The fact that `self` is an anonymous class within RSpec's `describe` is not really relevant
- Instead of using an instance method of `Class`, you can define your own class and associated class method and "share" that instead, as in the following:

  class Foo
    def self.bar(arg)
      puts(arg)
    end
  end

  describe "Sharing stringio" do

  Foo.class_eval do
      def self.puts(*args)
        MyStringIO.my_io.print(*args)
      end
    end

  class MyStringIO
      @my_io = StringIO.new
      def self.my_io ; @my_io ; end
    end

  it 'says "Welcome"' do
      Foo.bar("Welcome")
      expect(MyStringIO.my_io.string).to eql "Welcome"
    end

  end

Comment: I am so sorry, I didn't know that `Logger` was a Ruby module :). I meant to represent a generic class to be tested (which I unfortunately named `Logger` too). So the point was testing a generic class indeed.
PS: anyway, when you create `@my_io` and reference it inside `class_eval`, doesn't that `@my_io` refer to a `Logger` class variable? (given that `self` points to `Logger`).

Comment: You're right, of course. Sorry about, that. I had a disconnect between my edit window and what I was testing. ;-) Anyway, I updated the answer and took into account you didn't intend to reference Ruby's Logger.

Answer (score 0):

`Logger` already allows the output device to be specified on [construction](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/logger/Logger:initialize), so you can easily pass in your `StringIO` directly without having to redefine anything:

```
require 'logger'

describe Logger do

  let(:my_io) { StringIO.new }
  let(:log)   { Logger.new(my_io) }

  it 'says welcome' do
    log.error('Welcome')
    expect(my_io.string).to include('ERROR -- : Welcome')
  end
end
```

As other posters have mentioned, it's unclear whether you're intending to test `Logger` or some code that uses it.  In the case of the latter, consider [injecting](http://kresimirbojcic.com/2011/11/19/dependency-injection-in-ruby.html) the logger into the client code.

The answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917566/ruby-share-logger-instance-among-module-classes) also show several ways to share a common `Logger` between clients.

Comment: There was a misunderstanding, see the comment on Peter's answer.

Comment: Ah, i see.  I would actually suggest using the same design the stdlib Logger does: allow the concrete output device to be injected (during construction or through a setter).  This makes it very easy to test (just pass in a `StringIO`) and moreover decouples your `Logger` from the actual logging target - all with very little hassle and no hacks.