# Rails: Log stuff to rails app logs from any ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

I want to be able to log things to my Rail's app logs from a ruby class.

I was hoping to do `logger.info "some stuff"` from a class in `my_app/app/myClass.rb`, but  it's not defined. When I use `logger` in my controllers and elsewhere it works.

I'm a bit new to Rails / Ruby, and I'm assuming this is simply because the `logger` class isn't included in `myClass.rb`, but it is automatically included in all controllers, models, etc.

How can I include the `logger` class in an arbitrary ruby class, or otherwise log to my rails app from a ruby class?

(Added tag for "Pundit" since specifically I am using logger in a Pundit policy file, but it's just a ruby class :P)

Comment: i just did this the other day and this helped me out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917566/ruby-share-logger-instance-among-module-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create your own logger:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
     @app_logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/app.log")
  end

  def othermethod
     @app_logger.info("anything here")
  end 
end
```

Comment: Wouldnt this only be usable in files that were loaded after application controller?

Comment: what you mean by doesnt work? what is the error message?

Comment: NameError (undefined local variable or method `app_logger' for #<MyClass:0x007fb4c60f6f18>). Which is the same error when `logger` isn't defined. Again I think this is due to this class being loaded before application_controller, which is why logger isn't available either

Comment: if you are going to use the logger only in this class, initialize app_logger in this class

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now I'm not getting an error any more, but this still doesn't log anything to the app logs.

Comment: `@app_logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/app.log")`

and

`@app_logger.info('testing app logger')` in my initialize

Comment: try creating an empty app.log file in log directory

Answer (score 0):

You can load the app's logger into a method on `Object` during the rails app initialization process

```
# config/initializers/my_logger.rb

class Object
  def mylog
    @logger ||= Rails.logger
  end
end
```

Enhancing / changing the `Object` class should be done with care